# Can we measure the “visual taste” of a person in arts?

Tags: research

I was always thinking that the visual taste – or whatever it’s called – of a person is a gift from god and is innate.
But can we measure someone’s taste in graphic design – or arts in general?
I am asking because I am trying to develop a tool that measure the visual taste of people.

Comment: Taste definitely develops, so you can both learn it and re-prime your audience to consider new things tasteful.

Answer (score 1):

You can select whatever criteria you like to the device, because there still exists no scientifically based measures. Your problem is a marketing one - how to make your machine to be thought the only right way to measure the taste.

Give the result as single number between 0 to 100 without units and more complex dimensionality. A simple plain number need no explanations.

You can gain some plausibility by measuring only people, not their works. A hint: The measurement should be made possible only from the internals of the eye - both eyes at the same time and no possiblity to cheat by keeping something else as the target. Have a secret way to cancel any measurement! It's your key to repeatability and people likely believe the results only if your machine look into object's head.

Be sure that you say you measure the taste, not the ability to create something!

Sounds offtopic. How this is connected to graphic design? - As I wrote, your main problem will be the marketing - to make the output of the machine the one and only truth. This will require an enormous amount of top-notch graphic design work among the other efforts. See, how a brown carbon-dioxide solution have turned to most needful dirinkable, more important than pure water and how fat, farina, slaughtering waste, salt and chemicals have turned to valuable foodstuff.